AWS Lambda: "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'openai' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
I have created a node.js program that I am trying to deploy on AWS Lambda but I get the following error when trying to import OpenAI module.
{
 "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'openai' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'openai' imported from /var/task/index.mjs",
    "    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:858:9)",
    "    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:931:18)",
    "    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1161:14)",
    "    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1204:79)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)",
    "    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)",
    "    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)",
    "    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)"
  ]
}

My Code:
import { OpenAI } from 'openai';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const openaiApiKey = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY; // Use environment variable for the API key

const openai = new OpenAI(openaiApiKey);

// Define the Lambda handler function
export const handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        // Log the incoming event for debugging
        console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

        // Extract user message from query string parameters or the request body
        const userMessage = (event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.text) || JSON.parse(event.body).text || 'Hello, GPT!';

        const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [
                { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
                { role: "user", content: userMessage }
            ],
        });

        // Return the response with the output from OpenAI
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ output: completion.choices[0].message.content })
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Log the error message for debugging
        console.error('Error:', error.message);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({error: 'Error processing request'})
        };
    }
};

Although I have already tried installing the OpenAI module through Cloud9 portal. It worked when my function was in Python but when I am dealing with Node.js I am facing this issue. My node version is 20.x same as that on Cloud9 portal.

Either package and deploy the openai library and dependencies with your Lambda function or supply them via a Lambda Layer.
